# Template suggestion does not work

Tags: 7, theming

By debug, these are the suggested names:

```
 FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * panels-pane--fieldable-panels-pane-top-hero-content.tpl.php
   x panels-pane--fieldable-panels-pane--uuid-00524104-9c1e-4ee7-a896-270b5d30d935.tpl.php
   * panels-pane--fieldable-panels-pane.tpl.php
   * panels-pane.tpl.php
```

However, I can't get `panels-pane--fieldable-panels-pane-top-hero-content.tpl.php` to load.
I copied the file to the next name `panels-pane--fieldable-panels-pane--uuid-00524104-9c1e-4ee7-a896-270b5d30d935.tpl.php` and it DOES work.

What can be wrong? Both files are in the same directory.

Comment: Not sure why debug would be wrong but maybe try two dashes after fieldable-panels-pane - so panels-pane--fieldable-panels-pane--top-hero-content.tpl.php.

Comment: @othermachines  I hardcoded the name (i.e. not using $variables['pane]->panel) to generate the name, and now it works. Strange

Comment: In theme suggestions if the string variable you're using contains dashes, it might not work, so you need to replace the dashes with underscores using str_replace() for example